# Re-positioning two divs from a column format on smaller screens to a single row on wider screens

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have made a basic layout for a football scoreboard using flexbox.

The view has two separate views: large screens and small screens.

Here is what the large screen layout looks like:

[image]

Here is what the small screen layout looks like:

[image]

**My question is: On the large screen layout, what is a good way for me to be able to position the `corner-a` and `corner-b` so that they are level with the `carded-players` row, while maintaining the layout on small screens?**

The struggle I have experienced with this is that on small screens, it feels like I should wrap the two `corner` divs in their own `corners` wrapper, as is the case at the moment. On large screens, it feels like the two divs should not have a `corners` wrapper and just sit on their own in the corners of the `wrap` container.

What is a good way to solve this, without duplicating HTML?

CSS (compiled from SCSS):

```
@media (min-width: 601px) {
  .desktop-hide {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .mobile-hide {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid seagreen;
  max-width: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  max-width: 600px;
  min-width: 550px;
  border: 1px solid orangered;
}

.timer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.left-col, .right-col {
  max-width: 300px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.team {
  background: chartreuse;
}

.score {
  background: brown;
}

.scorers {
  background: steelblue;
}

.cards-desktop {
  background: goldenrod;
}

.carded-players {
  background: darkorange;
}

.left-col, .right-col {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.left-col * >, .right-col * > {
  display: flex;
}

.top > div {
  padding: 5px;
}

.bottom > div {
  height: 25px;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 100px;
}

.team,
.scorers {
  height: 50%;
  width: 75%;
}

.score {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 28px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .main {
    min-width: 100%;
  }

  .top {
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    height: initial;
  }

  .team, .scorers {
    height: initial;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .score {
    flex: 1 100px;
    align-self: flex-end;
  }

  .scorers {
    order: 1;
  }
}

.right-col .score {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.right-col .top {
  flex-flow: column wrap-reverse;
}

.left-col .top > *:not(.score), .left-col .bottom > * {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.team, .scorers {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.empty {
  height: 28px;
}

.colon {
  height: 95px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.corners {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.corner-left, .corner-right {
  border: 1px solid crimson;
}
```

Codepen link: http://codepen.io/alanbuchanan/pen/dMgJZg?editors=1100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout you want is possible with a combination of CSS positioning and media queries.

First, you can get rid of all this unnecessary code:

*duplicate html (desktop and mobile versions)*

```
<!-- REMOVE
<div class="corner-a mobile-hide">corner a</div>
<div class="corner-b mobile-hide">corner b</div>
<div class="corners desktop-hide">
     <div class="corner-left">corner-a</div>
     <div class="corner-right">corner-b</div>
</div>
-->
```

As suggested in your question, using duplicate HTML is not an optimal solution.

*also remove obsolete css*

```
/* 
@media (min-width: 601px) {
     .desktop-hide {
          display: none !important;
     }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
     .mobile-hide {
          display: none !important;
     }
}
*/
```

---

Second, add the corner elements as the last child of `.left-col` and `.right-col`.

```
<div class="left-col">
     <div class="top"> ...  </div>
     <div class="bottom"> ...  </div>
     <div class="corner-a">corner a</div><!-- new location -->
</div>

<div class="right-col">
     <div class="top"> ...  </div>
     <div class="bottom"> ...  </div>
     <div class="corner-b">corner b</div><!-- new location -->
</div>
```

---

Third, enable the corners to accept flex properties by making the parents flex containers:

```
.left-col,
.right-col {
     display: flex;               /* new */
     flex-direction: column;      /* new */
     max-width: 300px;
     width: 80%;
     margin: auto;
}
```

---

Fourth, style the corners for smaller screens:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {

     .corner-a {
          align-self: flex-start;
          position: static;
     }

     .corner-b {
          align-self: flex-end;
          position: static;
     }

}
```

---

Fifth, style the corners for wider screens.

```
.wrapper {
     border: 1px solid seagreen;
     max-width: 800px;
     display: flex;
     flex-flow: column wrap;
     align-items: center;
     position: relative;    /* new */
}

.corner-a {
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
  }

.corner-b {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
}
```

---

NOTES:

- For smaller screens, the corners are positioned in the layout per the document flow. They are aligned with flex properties.
- For wider screens the corners are removed from the document flow with absolute positioning. They are then positioned within their container (defined as the element which is the nearest positioned ancestor). This would be `.wrapper`. On smaller screens the corners are restored to the normal flow with `position: static`.

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxQgvo?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

Try nesting this code inside your '.corners' rule.

```
@media(min-width: 680px) {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1.25em;
}
```

If I understand your problem correctly, this will nudge your corners-a/corners-b elements up to the row of your carded-players row as the layout shift allows room.  The relative position property maintains the elements position in the document flow while allowing additional control without adding margin/padding.

Answer (score 0):

While there may be a good flexbox solution (I'm no expert on it), there are two options that I see you can try, although one is a bit hackey.

First option is adding the two corner divs into the same parent as your main content. In the DOM, put both divs after your other content, and use `float:left/right;` on the respective corner divs. You'll have to look into how to do this with flexbox.

The other, hackey but simpler solution is to add

```
margin-top:-20px;
```

To your .corner class, and under your media query, add

```
margin-top:0px;
```

Note that while transitioning between a large and small screen, the corners do overlap the main content a bit, so you may want to put the 0 margin property under a media query with max-width being a little greater than the main query. (This is why this solution is hackey).

Also change px units to em or vh, whatever works for your application best.